# Displaying images using opencv running on remote host, on local display?

Tags: opencv, embedded, gtk

I have a simple piece of code which uses openCV, and I want to run it on an ARM development board (freescale MX) which has no display attached to it. 
I've been trying for few days now to run the code on this remote device, and display its graphical output on my local machine, with no luck...

My setup:

- Ubuntu 10.04 on my local machine
- Linux 2.6 running on the board, with all the relevant packages I could think of.
- Ethernet connection to my local machine
- openCV compiled statically with GTK enabled
- using GDB/GDBServer for debug using SSH

and everything is running just fine accept for openCV's HIGHGUI display functions, which have no affect.

Some notes:

- I can set the DISPLAY env var to point to my local machine, and I get
  gtk-demo/xterm/whatever-is-using-X to appear on my local machine,
  even when running from the same SSH session I use for running and
  debugging my code.
- I'm trying to avoid getting into GTK/QT and patching/ preparing my own display wrapper. I got the feeling that I just need a small modification to the GTK/HIGHGUI config to make this work...

My code (which compiles and runs ok, accept for having no graphical output):

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("/root/capture.jpg");
//im is valid and not empty at this point
cvNamedWindow( "test" );
cv::imshow( "test", im);
cvWaitKey();
cvDestroyWindow( "test" );
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

---

Update:

Solved

While reading the message I've just posted, I found out that - I actually used getchar() instead of cvWaitKey(), which seems to be important...

Comment: Have you executed any X11 application on the remote ARM board that was successfully displayed on your local machine? I don't think this issue is exclusive to OpenCV.